# Rails + JQuery sidebar dropdown closes immediately

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to integrate a bootstrap theme (https://github.com/azouaoui-med/pro-sidebar-template) into my rails application but I'm having trouble getting the dropdowns inside the sidebar to work.
It appears to be a JQuery issue, and seeing as I'm very new to it, I'd love to get some input.

Here's my `chiller_theme.js` file:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
  $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
  if (
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .hasClass("active")
  ) {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .next(".sidebar-submenu")
      .slideDown(200);
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .addClass("active");
  }
});

$("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
});
$("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
});




});
```

And my `application.js` file:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require landing_page
//= require froala_editor.min.js
//= require plugins/font_family.min.js
//= require plugins/link.min.js
//= require chiller_theme.js
//= require_tree .

$(document).on("turbolinks:load",function(){
  $('.tag-tooltip').tooltip();
})

$('selector').froalaEditor();
```

And here's the `application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%= render 'layouts/rails_default' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/meta' %>
    <%= render 'application/favicon' %>
  </head>

  <body id="top">
  <div class="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
    <% if controller_name == 'lessons' && action_name == 'show' %>
      <%= render 'layouts/lessons_header' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% end %>
  <a id="show-sidebar" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">makers pro</a>
        <div id="close-sidebar">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="user-pic">
          <%= gravatar_for current_user %>
        </div>
        <div class="user-info">
          <span class="user-name"><%= current_user.first_name + ' ' + current_user.last_name %>
          </span>
          <span class="user-role"><%= @shop.title %></span>
          <!--  <span class="user-status">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
            <span>Online</span>
          </span> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-header  -->
      <div class="sidebar-search">
        <div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control search-menu" placeholder="Search Etsy">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-search  -->
      <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="header-menu">
            <span>General</span>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
              <span>Dashboard</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">New</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 1
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Pro</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              <span>E-commerce</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">3</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Products

                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Orders</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Credit cart</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-menu  -->
    </div>
    <!-- sidebar-content  -->
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning notification">3</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success notification">7</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        <span class="badge-sonar"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- sidebar-wrapper  -->
  <main class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

  </main>
  <!-- page-content" -->
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
<!-- page-wrapper -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <a href="#top" class="back-to-top"><%= icon('fas','angle-up') %></a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea on what might be causing the conflict?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> In your application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%= render 'layouts/rails_default' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/meta' %>
    <%= render 'application/favicon' %>
  </head>

  <body id="top">
  <div class="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
    <% if controller_name == 'lessons' && action_name == 'show' %>
      <%= render 'layouts/lessons_header' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% end %>
  <a id="show-sidebar" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">makers pro</a>
        <div id="close-sidebar">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="user-pic">
          <%= gravatar_for current_user %>
        </div>
        <div class="user-info">
          <span class="user-name"><%= current_user.first_name + ' ' + current_user.last_name %>
          </span>
          <span class="user-role"><%= @shop.title %></span>
          <!--  <span class="user-status">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
            <span>Online</span>
          </span> -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-header  -->
      <div class="sidebar-search">
        <div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control search-menu" placeholder="Search Etsy">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-search  -->
      <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="header-menu">
            <span>General</span>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
              <span>Dashboard</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">New</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu" style="display: none;">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 1
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Pro</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              <span>E-commerce</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">3</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu" style="display: none;">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Products

                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Orders</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Credit cart</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-menu  -->
    </div>
    <!-- sidebar-content  -->
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning notification">3</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success notification">7</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        <span class="badge-sonar"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- sidebar-wrapper  -->
  <main class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

  </main>
  <!-- page-content" -->
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
<!-- page-wrapper -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <a href="#top" class="back-to-top"><%= icon('fas','angle-up') %></a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Add inline css `style="display: none;"` to class `sidebar-submenu` and check it should work as expected.
Because you need to hide these sub menu on page load.

Comment: Didn't work. It's closed on page load, but once you click on it to expand, it closes right away. Any ideas?

Comment: oh.. I just copied your code and tried on my system.. it works.. can you elaborate your issue and add more code so I can debug on my end?

Comment: Thank you :) here's a video of what it looks like on my end: https://www.loom.com/share/fe7d501ce28b41c8adc1efbeaf0a4be8 . It happens on two different devices, both on firefox and chrome, what other code do you need?

Comment: I saw the video you shared.. I means another JS is impacting your code. try to print anything in console on clicking on the dropdown and make sure it is not clicking twice..

Comment: @MaayanNaveh Prashant is right. I integrated several times layouts in my applications. The js files you are importing may cause some issues, sometimes connected to turbolinks, sometimes to the styling. For this reason comment this assets one by one and test the application, once you find the asset breaking your functionality, comment the code and find the problem

Comment: @PrashantPatil and @fabrizio the console is printing no errors, doesn't appear to be clicking twice. I also commented out all my assets, including inline scripts. This is what I have left: `//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery3` and it still does the same. If I remove any one of these, it doesn't open the menu at all. Thanks for your help!